# Asyncio is not working within my Python3.7 lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7, python-asyncio

I am trying to create a python3.7 lambda which correctly uses asyncio for threading.

I have tried many different code variations but here is the latest block.  I am using AWS Xray to look at the timing and it is easy to verify that the async is not working correctly.   All these tasks and calls are being done synchronously.

```py
import json
import boto3
import asyncio
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch_all

#xray
patch_all()

def lambda_handler(event, context):  
    tasks = []
    dict_to_populate = {}

    for item in list:
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(do_work(item, dict_to_populate)))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    loop.close


async def do_work(item, dict_to_populate):
    #assume regions are obtained
    for region in regions:
        response_vpcs = describe_vpcs(obj['Id'], session_assumed, region)

        if 'Vpcs' in response_vpcs:
            for vpc in response_vpcs['Vpcs']:
                #process
```

I expect to see the do_work functions started at essentially the same time (asynchronously) but they are all synchronous according to XRAY.  It is processing synchronously and is populating dict_to_populate as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is how i have done in my aws lambda, I wanted to do 4 post request and then collect all the responses. Hope this helps.

```
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    if loop.is_closed():
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    #The perform_traces method i do all the post method
    task = loop.create_task(perform_traces(payloads, message, contact_centre))
    unique_match, error = loop.run_until_complete(task)
    loop.close()
```

In the `perform_trace` method this is how i have used wait with session

```
    future_dds_responses = []

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        for payload in payloads:
            future_dds_responses.append(dds_async_trace(session, payload, contact_centre))

        dds_responses, pending = await asyncio.wait(future_dds_responses)
```

In `dds_async_trace` this is how i have done the post using the aiohttp.ClientSession session

```
        async with session.post(pds_url,
                                data=populated_template_payload,
                                headers=PDS_HEADERS,
                                ssl=ssl_context) as response:
            status_code = response.status
```

Comment: Can you update answer as if there were multiple tasks, i.e a loop as I had it.  For example is it ```loop.run_until_complete(*tasks)``` assuming I've pushed to an array?

Comment: I actually ended up moving to concurrent.futures because asyncio was just not working as expected.